# Prefix Expression to Binary Tree Generator

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have some prefix expressions which are too long to feasibly create my own binary trees by hand. I was wondering if there was a latex package which could parse my expressions and automatically create a binary tree?

Take for example a smaller expression;

```
* - J % J 2 + 2 1
```

I want a binary tree automatically created like so.

[image]

So my terminals are {J, 0, 1, 2, 3} and my functions are {%, /, *, -, +}. I'm hoping given this much information and the fact that the arity of each function is 2, and terminals obviously 0, that there is a package which could do this for me? Or maybe someone knows of a piece of software which can format an expression like this into tikz picture code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of the good tree drawing packages (in particular `tikz-qtree` and `forest`) accept some form of a bracketed structure, so drawing these trees is quite simple.

Here's an example with both packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
prefix tree/.style={for tree={draw,circle,minimum size=2em,edge=->}}
[*,prefix tree [- [J  [\%  [ J ] [ 2 ] ]] [+ [ 2 ] [ 1 ] ]]]
\end{forest}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=2em},
edge from parent/.style={draw, ->,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}}]
\Tree [.* [.- [.J  [.\%   J   2  ]] [.+  2   1 ]]]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

To automate this, here's a basic algorithm which you could implement in your favourite language, or for an integrated solution, implement it in Lua and use LuaTeX.

[Create a binary tree from an algebraic expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7866587)

Comment: Brilliant. Just what I was looking for. I think I will make a short C program. I will post a link when I have implemented it! Thank You!

Answer (score 6):

So after following Alan's answer, I wrote a small program in C (Win) that does a pre-order traversal and it worked a treat. After I finish my dissertation (which this is for), I will write a proper piece of software so it can be used easier by others (i.e. with inputs and automatic latex compilation) but for now here is the "hack".

```
void create_tex(char*);
int pointer = 0;
char *expression = "/+/*%+-J2*21+J%23%%-3J3++*21+J%23+/-022+0-03-*-++0-030*0J-03++0-030J++*21+J%23-+%+-J2*21+J%23*%+J%23*-++0-030*0J-03+J%23//-3J33\0";

    int main()
    {
        char tex_tree[2048];
        create_tex(tex_tree);
        getch();
        return 0;
    }

    void create_tex(char* tex_tree) {
        char a = expression[pointer];
        if (a == '\0')
            return;
        if (a == '+' || a == '*' || a == '/' || a == '-' || a == '%') {
            if (a == '%') 
                printf("[.\\%c ", a); 
            else
                printf("[.%c ", a); 
            pointer++;
            create_tex(tex_tree);
            pointer++;
            create_tex(tex_tree);
            printf("]");
        }
        else {
            printf("%c ", a); 
        }
    }
```

On that declaration of the expression char* it gives this output;

```
[./ [.+ [./ [.* [.\% [.+ [.- J 2 ][.* 2 1 ]][.+ J [.\% 2 3 ]]][.\% [.\% [.- 3 J ]3 ][.+ [.+ [.* 2 1 ][.+ J [.\% 2 3 ]]][.+ [./ [.- 0 2 ]2 ][.+ 0 [.- 0 3 ]]]]]][.- [.* [.- [.+ [.+ 0 [.- 0 3 ]]0 ][.* 0 J ]][.- 0 3 ]][.+ [.+ 0 [.- 0 3 ]]0 ]]]J ][.+ [.+ [.* 2 1 ][.+ J [.\% 2 3 ]]][.- [.+ [.\% [.+ [.- J 2 ][.* 2 1 ]][.+ J [.\% 2 3 ]]][.* [.\% [.+ J [.\% 2 3 ]][.* [.- [.+ [.+ 0 [.- 0 3 ]]0 ][.* 0 J ]][.- 0 3 ]]][.+ J [.\% 2 3 ]]]][./ [./ [.- 3 J ]3 ]3 ]]]]
```

which when put in this format;

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\resizebox{700pt}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=1em},
edge from parent/.style={draw, ->,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}}]
\Tree [./ [.+ [./ [.* [.\% [.+ [.- J 2 ][.* 2 1 ]][.+ J [.\% 2 3 ]]][.\% [.\% [.- 3 J ]3 ][.+ [.+ [.* 2 1 ][.+ J [.\% 2 3 ]]][.+ [./ [.- 0 2 ]2 ][.+ 0 [.- 0 3 ]]]]]][.- [.* [.- [.+ [.+ 0 [.- 0 3 ]]0 ][.* 0 J ]][.- 0 3 ]][.+ [.+ 0 [.- 0 3 ]]0 ]]]J ][.+ [.+ [.* 2 1 ][.+ J [.\% 2 3 ]]][.- [.+ [.\% [.+ [.- J 2 ][.* 2 1 ]][.+ J [.\% 2 3 ]]][.* [.\% [.+ J [.\% 2 3 ]][.* [.- [.+ [.+ 0 [.- 0 3 ]]0 ][.* 0 J ]][.- 0 3 ]]][.+ J [.\% 2 3 ]]]][./ [./ [.- 3 J ]3 ]3 ]]]]
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

Gives this output!

[image]

Thanks for your help @Alan Munn!